Book about a vampire who is tasked with watching over a woman whose boyfriend has been murdered
A human woman's boyfriend gets murdered, a vampire has been watching over her apartment sees it happening, he's been tasked with watching over her.
She gets a call from him saying he's got info on what happened. She goes to this abandoned place and she meets him. Sometime later they fall in love. She somehow awakens a God named Samuel, he fights his goddess mate. The human woman ends up becoming a vampire and, at the end, gets married to the vampire that had watched over her.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?  Was it a paperback, hardcover or e-book?

It was a few yrs ago, I thought I had bought it on kindle but can't find it, it was over 600 pages, I want to say the vampires name was joriko something like that, he's not the one that changed her, her throat was slashed and her friend gave her his blood so she could live, he didn't want her in that way he wanted to teach her how to fight, in the end he gave her away to the vampire that she loved to get married,  there's also twin creepy vampires, a disfigured little girl that gets taken by the goddess. I want to say the female that the vampire falls in love is a werewolf
